# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField gives me a ProgrammingError

Tags: django, modelchoicefield, modelmultiplechoicefield

I would like to get your help because I'm getting an issue which is a little bit weird to my mind.

I'm using `Django 1.11.16`

I have in my forms.py file this class :

```
class PublicationStatForm(forms.Form):
    # publication_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Publication.objects.all().order_by('pub_id'))
    publication_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Publication.objects.all().order_by('pub_id'),
        label=_('Publication Choice'),
        widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
            model=Publication,
            search_fields=['pub_id__icontains', 'title__icontains'],
            attrs={'data-placeholder': "Please select publication(s)"}
        )
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PublicationStatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, in my views.py file :

```
class StatsView(TemplateView):
    """ Create statistics pageview """
    template_name = 'freepub/stats.html'
    form_class = PublicationStatForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        subtitle = _("Statistics")
        context_data = super(StatsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['form'] = self.form_class()
        ...
        return context_data
```

And finally in my template, I just have :

```
<form class="date-form" method="GET">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        {{ form.publication_list }}
      </div>
   </div>
   <input id="submit-date-stats" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="SearchPublicationPeriod"
               value="{% trans 'Submit' %}"/><br/>
</form>
```

I don't understand why, when I have this line in my form it works :

```
# publication_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Publication.objects.all().order_by('pub_id'))
```

But when I replace this line by this :

```
publication_list = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Publication.objects.all().order_by('pub_id'),
    label=_('Publication Choice'),
    widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
        model=Publication,
        search_fields=['pub_id__icontains', 'title__icontains'],
        attrs={'data-placeholder': "Please select publication(s)"}
    )
)
```

I get this issue :

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /freepub/stats
Exception Value: relation "select_cache" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "select_cache"
                             ^
```

Do you have any idea ?

**EDIT : Add cache settings**

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    },
    # "default": {
    #     "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
    #     "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
    #     "OPTIONS": {
    #         "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
    #     }
    # },
    'select': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'select_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': None,
    }
}

# Set the cache backend to select2
SELECT2_CACHE_BACKEND = 'select'
```

Comment: Have you run makemigrations and migrate? I see the code difference is in forms, but worth checking off first.

Comment: I didn't touch to my models.py file but I can try.

Comment: I don't think it's likely to be that, but worth checking.  What Cache backend do you have setup, could you include that?

Comment: Yes I can, but I didn't handle cache setup during this process so I assume it doesn't come from that point ?

Comment: I think it might be, having been looking at the documentation earlier.  (Nice library btw, haven't run across this one before.) . I think the issue is that your select2 cache backend should be `select2` not `select` - which makes sense with the error you're getting that `select_cache` doesn't exist.

Comment: Missed a point off that - it's like the second cache you've defined there hasn't been created. edit: yes, realised what it is, answer coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your cache settings.

Although you've set up a database cache backend, you need to run `python manage.py createcachetable` to actually create it in the database, similar to how you run `migrate` for regular model changes or additions - and is also why the error looks similar, which took me down the migrations route at first.

The Django `ProgrammingError` exception is an extension of the base DatabaseError, so it always relates to something wrong in the database.  ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/db/utils/#ProgrammingError) )

This wouldn't be the case if you use a redis or other KV store cache, as it will automatically insert it.  Because the Django database cache uses a table in the same database, that table has to be created, per [this section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#creating-the-cache-table).

Comment: I don't have issue about cache thanks to your comment. I will validate it, but my form doesn't still work. Maybe I will create a new question.

Comment: Thanks!  Hopefully i can help with that too. :)